# Determine if current time falls within multiple time ranges

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timespan, range

I wrote a simple application that displays the current time (HH:MM).
The displayed time is refreshed every second a DispatcherTimer.

Considering I have a "configuration" file in XML format that contains a list of hours that must be displayed highlighted in a different color for 5 minutes:

Example:

- 08:15 → highlighted from 8:15 until 8:20 inclusive
- 10:20 → highlighted from 10:20 until 10:25 inclusive
- 11:55 → highlighted from 11:55 until 12:00 inclusive
- 14:15 → highlighted from 14:15 until 14:20 inclusive
- 16:05 → highlighted from 16:05 until 16:10 inclusive

But if there are "overlapping" possibilities, like:

- 08:10
- 08:12

Then the time should be highlighted from 8:15 until 08:17

How would you implement your code which will check wheather the current/actual time is within these ranges?

Will you generate first a list with all start+end times for each entry and check the actual time against this list each second? (looping through all the list values each second)? :-/

Or will you achieve this in another way and how?

EDIT: Here is what has been done so far:

```
private enum DisplayState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The application has just been started or reset due to changes to the configuration file
    /// </summary>
    Initial,

    /// <summary>
    /// The current displayed time is highlighed
    /// </summary>
    Highlighted,

    /// <summary>
    /// The current displayed time is not highlighed
    /// </summary>
    Normal
};

DisplayState _lastDisplayState = DisplayState.Initial;

// The list that retrieves the hours from the XML file as string values ("HH:MM")
// Note: this can be changed into a list of TimeSpan or anything else in a near future
private List<string> _hourList;

private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
```

...

```
/// <summary>
/// What happens each second
/// </summary>
private void dispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Store current time
    _timeToDisplay = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

    // Refresh displayed time
    tbDigitalClock.Text = tbDigitalClockBack.Text = _timeToDisplay;

    PlaceWindow();

    // Check if our list of hours contain current time
    // Note: for the moment _hourList is a list of strings (hours from the XML file)
    if (_hourList.Contains(_timeToDisplay))
    {
        // Only change appearance once if display state changed
        if (_lastDisplayState != DisplayState.Highlighted)
        {
            _lastDisplayState = DisplayState.Highlighted;

            // Play sound alert if desired
            if (_playSound)
                _soundPlayer.Play();

            // Highlight current displayed time
            tbDigitalClock.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
            tbDigitalClockBack.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
            mainBorder.Background = _highlightedBackColor;
            mainBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_lastDisplayState != DisplayState.Normal)
        {
            _lastDisplayState = DisplayState.Normal;

            // Turn displayed time appearance back to normal
            tbDigitalClock.Foreground = _defaultTextColor;
            tbDigitalClockBack.Foreground = _defaultTextBackColor;
            mainBorder.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            mainBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file looks like:

```
<DigiClock>
    <Config PlaySound="true" />
    <Breaks>
        <Time>10:00</Time>
        <Time>12:00</Time>
        <Time>14:30</Time>
        <Time>16:30</Time>
    </Breaks>
</DigiClock>
```

Many thanks in advance! ;-)

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? This is an opinionated question.

Comment: Hi, I added what has been done so far. Thanks

Comment: It's not about how *we will implement the code*, but what *you have tried that didn't work*.

Comment: Well I haven't implemented this yet because I still wonder "what is the best way/alternative to determine if the current time is within those ranges". That's whay I posted this question :-)

Comment: I thought about 2 things: a) first creating dynamically a List of object with start and end (calculated) hours, then checking against this list each second (foreach) OR b) each second, performing a test looping through the hours from XML (start time) and end time (start time + 5 min). Option b) seems even worse than a) :-/ Do you think about something else better (less consuming)? Thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are coding a GUI application, I would go with a timer with its interval set to 1 second (or maybe 5 seconds is enough? or something in between?) and with an event handler similar to this (untested) one:

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // five minutes
List<DateTime> _hourList;
bool _soundPlayed = false;

private void OnTimerTick()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var h in _hourList)
    {
        if ((now >= h) && (now <= (h + t)))
        {
            if (_lastDisplayState != DisplayState.Highlighted)
            {
                _lastDisplayState = DisplayState.Highlighted;
                ...
            }

            if (!_soundPlayed)
            {
                _soundPlayed = true;
                _soundPlayer.Play();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    // if code runs until here, we are out of any highlighted moment
    _soundPlayed = false;
    if (_lastDisplayState != DisplayState.Normal)
    {
        _lastDisplayState = DisplayState.Normal;
        ...
    }
}
```